# Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to run my application but it keeps outputting this message:

```
    Process: com.casmanager, PID: 8249
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.casmanager/com.casmanager.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3229)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.casmanager.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3066)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3229)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class TextView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class TextView
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 5: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f030214 a=-1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:546)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:3867)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1243)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1102)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:99)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:95)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:207)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:281)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:193)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:104)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.casmanager.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3066)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3229)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

This error seems to happen due to an error inflating the NavigationView in the layout I use for my main activity, but I can't find out why. All my attributes and drawables are correctly typed and available. FYI, I am using homepage.xml as my activity layout and main_menu.xml as my navigation layout.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.casmanager.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.casmanager.activity_recyclerview.Activity;
import com.casmanager.fragment.ActivityFragment;
import com.casmanager.fragment.LoggerFragment;
import com.casmanager.fragment.ReflectionFragment;
import com.casmanager.interfaces.MainView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.casmanager.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    //Initializing all the view objects used in the homepage
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    MenuItem darkTheme;
    int themeId;

    @Override
    public void setTheme(int themeId) {
        super.setTheme(themeId);
        this.themeId = themeId;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homepage);

        //Initializing toolbar in main activity
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Setting up navigation drawer views and selected item listener to determine which item is being selected
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        //Setting start-up selected menu item
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);

        //Sets up action bar menu collapsible toggle
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,
                R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        //Loads default homepage activity fragment
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_fragment, new ActivityFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    public void restartApp() {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.activities) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, new ActivityFragment(), "ACTIVITIES");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.reflections) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, new ReflectionFragment(), "REFLECTIONS");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.logger) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, new LoggerFragment(), "LOGGER");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }

}
```

homepage.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">


  <include
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      layout="@layout/drawer_toolbar"/>

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

main_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item android:title="General">

        <menu>

            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/activities"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_myplaces"
                android:title="Activities" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/reflections"
                    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
                    android:title="Reflections" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/logger"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/presence_away"
                android:title="Logger" />

            </group>

        </menu>

    </item>


</menu>
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: FOUND ERROR

I was using an attribute ?attr/textColor that was meant to be for setting separate light and dark mode fonts, but this didn't really work well as seen from the error. Setting the android:textColor attribute worked fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add these dependencies in your:     build.gradle(Module: app)

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
```